# Replacing category name with category description in woocommerce products page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to replace the category name with category description (only if category description is not empty) with the below script:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'bbloomer_show_all_subcats', 2 );
 
function bbloomer_show_all_subcats() {
   global $product;
   $cats = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
   $cat_descr = join('', wp_list_pluck($cats, 'description'));
   $categ = join('', wp_list_pluck($cats, 'name'));
   if ($cat_descr){
   echo '<div class="mf-catalog-title">'.$cat_descr.'</div>';
   } else {
   echo '<div class="mf-catalog-title">'.$categ.'</div>';
   }
}
```

The script is working but when I have same products in two categories, the category name is duplicating. When I have a category description, is not duplicating. Only the category name does it. Why does this happen?

The theme displays from his own the category name, but I hide this with some CSS. Which php hook (remove_action) disappears the category name?

Thanks.

Comment: I would also like to know why you echo the whole `<div>` when only the text inside of the div is conditional.  What are your values for `$cat_descr` and `$categ`?  Your [mcve] could be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution myself.

```
function cat_description() {
   global $product;
   $cats = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
   $cat_descr = wp_list_pluck($cats, 'description');
   $cat_name = wp_list_pluck($cats, 'name');
   echo '<div class="mf-catalog-title">';
   if ($cat_descr[0]){
   echo $cat_descr[0];
   } else {
   echo $cat_name[0];
   }
   echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'cat_description', 2 );
```